# load json and show in #each block; Uncaught Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

In Svelte (3) I'm loading JSON via the rollup json plugin and am trying to do a #each loop in the template

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import * as quests from './quests.json';
</script>

<main>
    <h1>DDO Hardcore Favor Planner</h1>
    {#each quests as quest}
        {quest.name}
    {/each}
</main>
```

I'm getting

`Uncaught Error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects.`

example json excerpt

```
[
  {
    "name": "Violent Delights",
    "level": 1,
    "pack": "Keep on the Borderlands",
    "patron": "The Gatekeepers",
    "favor": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "The Hobgoblin Horde",
    "level": 1,
    "pack": "Keep on the Borderlands",
    "patron": "The Gatekeepers",
    "favor": 3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import was wrong

Instead of

`import * as quests from './quests.json';`

use

`import quests from './quests.json';`

Comment: `* as quests` seems to make quests some kind of top level object. If you use this: ` import * as questsD from './quests.json';
  let quests=questsD.default`, it will work also